# Finite element method with two different Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: boundary-value-problem, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

I have the problem like this
$$
 -\Delta u = f \ \ \text{on}\ \Omega \\
 u = g_1 \ \  \text{on} \ \partial \Omega_1 \\
u = g_2 \ \  \text{on} \ \partial \Omega_2
$$
If we choose

$$
V_1 = \{ \nu_1 \in H^1 : \nu_1 = 0 \ \text{on}\ \partial \Omega_1 \bigcup \partial \Omega_2 \} \\
V_2 = \{ \nu_2 \in H^1 : \nu_2 = g_1 \ \text{on}\ \partial \Omega_1 \ \text{and}\ \nu_2 = g_2 \ on\  \partial \Omega_2 \}
$$

If $v\ \in V_1$ and $u\ \in \ V_2$, and decompose $u$ into three regions $u = u_{ \Omega}+ u_ {\partial \Omega_1} + u_{\partial \Omega_2}$, the week formulation of the problem using this definition would be

$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot\nabla \nu_1 dx = \int_{\Omega} f \nu_1 dx - \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_{g_1}\cdot\nabla \nu_1 dx - \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_{g_2}\cdot\nabla \nu_1 dx
$$
Would the definition of basis function, particularly on boundaries be correct, i.e. forcing to be zero on two boundaries for $V_1$, in addition using the definition of $V_2$ for $u$ from trace theorem point of view, i.e. if there is a trace operator that $\gamma_1 u = g_1$ and $\gamma_2 u = g_2$ where $\gamma$ is trace operator?

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what is your question. Are you asking how is the formula for the weak formulation with the Dirichlet boundary contribution implemented on the finite element level (or vector and matrix level)? Because basis function are typically defined independent on the problem you want to solve so there cannot be clash in that.

Comment: @Korf Thanks Korf for the comment. I added more details to make the question more clear. My question, particularly, is about trace operators, more precisely if there is trace operator such that $\gamma_1 u = g_1$ and $\gamma_2 u = g_2$.